# .replace problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with `html().replace`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function() { 
  jQuery(".post_meta_front").html(jQuery(".post_meta_front").html().replace(/\<p>Beschreibung:</p> /g, '<span></span>'));
});
</script>
```

what is wrong in my script?

Comment: It would be good if you described what the problem is. And posted your HTML or at least a short extract.

Comment: need quotes around the regex maybe?

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using regex for this?

If you want to replace an element with another, you can use [jQuery's `.replaceWith()` method](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith).

```
jQuery(".post_meta_front p:contains('Beschreibung:')")
                                               .replaceWith('<span></span>');
```

Or if you need to ensure an exact match on the content:

```
jQuery(".post_meta_front p").filter(function() {
    return $.text([ this ]) === 'Beschreibung:';
}).replaceWith('<span></span>');
```

Comment: +1. Relying on the format of the output of `html()` at all is inadvisable (different browsers will give different text escaping, element case and attribute quoting formatting). Using DOM-style methods like this is more reliable, and doesn't unnecessarily destroy and re-create all the other nodes you are not replacing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape forward slashes `/` in the regex part.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function() { 
  jQuery(".post_meta_front").html(jQuery(".post_meta_front").html().replace(/<p>Beschreibung:<\/p> /g, '<span></span>'));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not escaping all of the special characters in the find parameter of the replace function.  You're only escaping the first `<` character.

Try something like:

```
/\<p\>Beschreibung:\<\/p\>/g
```

Note that replace is a function of javascript not jQuery.